# How to fill the background of a stat_poly_eq equation (ggpmisc) using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, equation, fill, ggpmisc

Is there a way to fill the background of a stat_poly_eq equation `ggpmisc` with white color (or any other color) so that the black lines of the panel.grid are hidden?

```
# Data
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:100))
df$y <- 2 + 3 * df$x + rnorm(100, sd = 40)
df$yy <- 2 + 3 * df$x + 0.1 * df$x^2 + rnorm(100, sd = 40)

# Graph
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,100), expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,400), expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_line(colour="black",size=0.1)) +
  stat_poly_line() +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(
    label = paste(after_stat(eq.label),
                  after_stat(rr.label), sep = "*\", \"*")), size = 6, label.x = 0.07, label.y = 0.78) +
  geom_point()
```

Below is the graph as I would like:

[image]

Thanks for help

Comment: The idea is not to remove the panel.grid, but rather that they do not intersect the equation (in other words, that the equation and its white background are positioned in the foreground to hide this panel.grid)

Comment: A function/argument to control the background of a stat_poly_eq equation (color, size...) would be aesthetically very useful in some contexts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved by switching the default `geom` used by `stat_poly_eq` to add the label. By default `ggpp::geom_text_npc` is used but there is also a `geom_label_npc`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,100), expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,400), expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_line(colour="black",size=0.1)) +
  stat_poly_line() +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(
    label = paste(after_stat(eq.label),
                  after_stat(rr.label), sep = "*\", \"*")), 
    size = 6, label.x = 0.07, label.y = 0.78, 
    geom = "label_npc", label.size = 0) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: great! thank you. We can add some other arguments to 'geom = "label_npc", label.size = 0' like alpha=0.5, colour = "red", fill = "pink"...However, do you think it is possible to control the size of the background, in height or in width?

Comment: It can be done using 'label.padding = grid::unit(0.5, "cm")' which is the amount of padding around label (defaults to 0.25 lines). Also possible to add 'label.r = grid::unit(0.5, "cm")' to control the radius of rounded corners (defaults to 0.15 lines). Thanks again.

Comment: An explanation: the reason why I decided to have "text_npc" as default is that a label, unless one is careful about its location, can accidentaly oclude observations.